# Read more link function on dynamically added elements not working

Tags: jquery, html, function

I have a function which sets see more link on long text..it works well on elements present before page load but doesnt work on dynamically added elements, I am calling shorten() function after adding elements, then it works only on newly added elements but the elements present before load and were working, doesnt work....below is my code and you can check jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/R4uRp/2/)

**HTML**

```
    <div class="main">
      <p class="readmore">this is some text this is some text this is some text this is some text this is some text this is some text this is some text this is some text this is some text this is some text this is some text text this is some text this is some text text this is some text this is some text text this is some text this is some text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="new-elem"></div>
    <a href="#" class="addElem">Add</a>
```

**JS**

```
jQuery.fn.shorten = function (settings) {
var config = {
    showChars: 100,
    ellipsesText: "...",
    moreText: "See More",
    lessText: "See Less"
};

if (settings) {
    jQuery.extend(config, settings);
}

jQuery('body').on('click', '.morelink', function () {
    var his = jQuery(this);
    if (his.hasClass('less')) {
        his.removeClass('less');
        his.html(config.moreText);
    } else {
        his.addClass('less');
        his.html(config.lessText);
    }
    his.parent().prev().toggle();
    his.prev().toggle();

    return false;
});

return this.each(function () {
    var his = jQuery(this);

    var content = his.html();
    if (content.length > config.showChars) {
        var c = content.substr(0, config.showChars);
        var h = content.substr(config.showChars, content.length - config.showChars);
        var html = c + '<span class="moreellipses">' + config.ellipsesText + '&nbsp;</span><span class="morecontent"><span>' + h + '</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="javascript://nop/" class="morelink">' + config.moreText + '</a></span>';
        his.html(html);
        jQuery(".morecontent span").hide();
    }
});
}

jQuery('.readmore').shorten();  //for load time

jQuery(document).on('click', '.addElem', function () {
    jQuery('.new-elem').append('<p class="readmore">this is some text this is some text this is some text this is some text this is some text this is some text this is some text this is some text this is some text this is some text this is some text</p>');
    jQuery('.readmore').shorten();  //for newly added elements


});
```

Comment: You are calling `jQuery(container)` but `container` doesn't seem to be defined anywhere.

Comment: Thats my code...I have to remove it...I pasted code to reproduce the problem

Comment: removed...and I think its not working still

Comment: I am looking at the fiddle and it seems to work fine now.

Comment: add elemnts check all the see more links, new and old elements

Comment: SO what could be the solution

Answer (score 0):

It seems like whenever the "Add" link is clicked, you are running the "shorten" function on all of the `.readmore` elements, which is attaching the `click` handler to the body more than once.

The first time the "Add" link is clicked, a paragraph is added, and the click handler is added 2 times (once for each of the 2 paragraphs), and clicking the "See More" link causes the handler to run 2 times. The 2nd time the click handler is clicked, another paragraph is added, and the click handler is added 3 more times, and clicking the "See More" link causes the handler to run 5 times. The next time the "Add" link is clicked, another paragraph is added, and the click handler is added to the body 4 more times. Clicking the "See More" link causes the handler to run 9 times. And so on.

I think the `jQuery('body').on('click'...)` call should be moved out of the `shorten` function. Also, `jQuery('.readmore').shorten();` should maybe be changed to `jQuery('.addElem .readmore:last').shorten();`. This will cause the `click` handler for the "See More" link to be attached only once, and it will cause the `shorten` method to be called only once for each of the `.readmore` links.